# Timber: Search results not working

Tags: wordpress, timber

I am using Timber to theme a WordPress site which is currently in a local dev environment. This is my first site with Timber. It has been a lot of fun to use, but I definitely still have some things to learn – particularly since I am more of a front-end dev and PHP is not my forte.

I am having difficulty getting my search results page to work. It appears that WordPress is ignoring the search.php files and using the index.php file. The search results I get simply display a tease of each 'Post' on the site which are unrelated to the search query. In addition to standard WordPress 'Post' and 'Page' content, I also have a CPT and ACF extended category content that needs to be displayed in search results.

I have both a search.php and search.twig file and I have determined that the right TWIG template is being used.

My search.php:

```
$templates = array( 'search.twig', 'archive.twig', 'index.twig' );
$context = Timber::get_context();

$context['title'] = 'Search results for '. get_search_query();
$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery();

Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

My index.php:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery(); //was: Timber::get_posts();

$templates = array( 'index.twig' );
if ( is_home() ) {
    array_unshift( $templates, 'search.twig', 'front-page.twig' );
}
Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

*Note that I added search.twig to the templates above because otherwise the search results page was using the front-page.twig template.*

My search.twig:

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Your search results for:</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="tease tease-{{post.post_type}}" id="tease-{{post.ID}}">
                <h2><a href="{{post.link}}">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
                <p>{{post.get_preview}}</p>
                {% if post.get_thumbnail %}
                    <img src="{{post.thumbnail.src}}" />
                {% endif %}
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And my search form code is simply:

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="{{site.url}}/">
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue getting search to work and here is what my files look like to get it working. I hope this helps:

Search.php

```
  $templates = array( 'search.twig', 'archive.twig', 'index.twig' );
  $context = Timber::get_context();

  $context['search_query'] = get_search_query();
  $context['posts'] = new Timber\PostQuery();
  $context['pagination'] = Timber::get_pagination();

  Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

.twig file

```
<form method="get" role="search" action="{{ site.url }}">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Keywords..." name="s">
  <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit button--green">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post">
</form>
```

The hidden input with the value="post" will limit to the scope of the search to only search 'post' post types. You can add in the name of your CPT's and it will only search through that particular CPT as well. The most important thing here in this html, which gave me a hard time, is the

```
name="s"
```

That is the query parameter WP is using to conduct the search.

Here is my search-results.twig template for reference in case you need that too:

```
<section class="section__news-search-results">
  {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="news-item__container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="image">
            {% if post.thumbnail.src %}
              <img src="{{post.thumbnail.src | resize(150, 150) }}" />
            {% endif %}
          </div> {# /.image #}
        </div> {# /.col #}

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
          <div class="copy">
            <p><small>{{ post.date }}</small></p>
            <p><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></p>
            <p>{{post.preview.length(25)}}</p>
          </div> {# /.copy #}
        </div> {# /.col #}
      </div> {# /.row #}
    </div> {# /.news-item__container #}
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert – I'll give this a try. I actually just figured out a workaround yesterday that I was going to post about. I installed the Redirection plug-in and created a Regex redirect. Source: `/?search=(.*)` Target: `s=$1`

Comment: You shouldn't need any .htaccess redirects, although if it's working great. By adding in name="s" to the input, WP will add the correct query parameter to the URL and it will work as expected. I banged my head for a long time before I figure that out lol

Comment: Wow! So easy, yet so elusive. That did the trick – thanks! While it’s wonderful to have search working in Timber, it would be great if a more user-friendly URL could be used. For now though, I'll take it. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @robertguss! Great explanation and it works brilliantly! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Search.php, you need to define your search query, likeso.

```
$get_search_query = $context['search_query'] =  get_search_query();
```

And debug on you search.php file if your posts returning something, otherwise you may use

```
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();
```

Finally, Your search form should look something like this

```
<form action="{{ site.link }}" role="search">
   <input name="search" type="search" autocomplete="off">
   <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

Try & Let me know if this works out.Good luck

Comment: Hi Usama - Thanks for taking a look. I tried adding the above to my search.php template, but unfortunately, nothing changed (I also tried all the usual things: hard clearing cache; resaving permalinks).  

I don't think WP/Timber is even looking at the search.php file. I have What the File plugin installed and it's telling me that the index.php file is being used to display the results.  

Interestingly, my search results page is using the query: `?search=[searchQuery]`. When I manually edit it to: `/?s=[searchQuery]` It does use the search.php template, I just don't get any results.

Comment: I managed to get search to work, but only by creating a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file (no function I wrote in the theme's functions.php file would affect the rewrite rules – not sure why that would be). Here's the .htaccess rewrite:  `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} search=(.*)  
RewriteRule ^$ /?s=%1 [R,L]`

Comment: @AlAvery Timber has nothing to do with Search at this point. Its the basic WordPress thing, we're just utilising the twig for listing search results. Can you debug at the search.php level? At whats returning from your $context['posts'] ?

Comment: Yes, I believe it's a template hierarchy issue, but a confusing one. In theory, search.php should take precedence when it exists in the theme root (it does). However, it appears that the index.php file is being used and the front-page.twig file for presentation. The code for my search.php file is above, but it is being bypassed. Something about the URL query is causing the index.php to be used. If I manually change the URL from `/?search=` to `/?s=` it works.

Comment: @AlAvery, I'm not just sure why its not working out. Check out the [WordPress docs for Search](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_search_query)
They are using **s** for their query param. If its working with s, then you may user it instead of **search** 
Try dumping your results from your search query & see where it will land.